# What are the challenges for delivering bulk asteroid commodities to Earth?

Tags: landing, asteroid, mining, economics

I think nickel-iron is an extraordinary and perhaps unique resource that is (by Earth market standards) valuable even as a raw and unprocessed commodity - perhaps several thousand US$ per ton for high nickel content would seem likely, with potential value in the precious metals mixed in probably exceeding that. But being mixed in at low concentrations in metal alloy, extracting and refining looks to be very challenging.

Rather than attempt it in space I think delivery to Earth might offer an alternative that minimises in-space costs. Relatively simple processing would be needed to extract nickel-iron - possibly from metal rich chondrites that have metal as grains or nodules within softer carbonaceous material. Or perhaps shattering at very low temperatures could be a low energy, low cost method of mining bulk nickel-iron.

Because of the costs of launching bulk cargo to space is so high I think any attempts to mine asteroids must ruthlessly limit the equipment and materials launched from Earth and rather than attempting to establish refineries to extract the high value elements from nickel-iron it may be better to deliver nickel-iron to Earth.

But can bulk "hard" materials be transported effectively (perhaps fueled by asteroid water broken down to H2 and O2) delivered at low cost to Earth's surface? How?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14157/6944

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3799/6944

Comment: [LME prices](https://www.lme.com/) for 6 Jul 2020: Nickel USD 13,040 per tonne & US Steel USD 479 per tonne. What nickel iron alloy would you like? I sure a foundry could make an "asteroid special" fairly cheaply. BTW, Gold is USD 1774 per troy oz, which is USD 82.4 per g, or 82.4 million USD per tonne & it's still economic to mine here on Earth. It might be more economic to use asteroid metals for items elsewhere in the cosmos.

Comment: Yeah, nickel iron is unlikely to be worth bringing to earth. Most asteroid mining projects are focused either on rare, exotic materials, precious metals, or stuff to be used in space (since it's conveniently already in space).

Comment: related: [How to get processed asteroid metals back to Earth in a safe manner](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14157/12102) and also [Atmospheric entry of asteroid mining products](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43912/12102)

Comment: If people want this closed as a duplicate I can withdraw it.

Comment: @Fred -  my issue with space resources used exclusively in space is that there is no economically profitable basis for growth without return trade with Earth. There is no separate economy.

Comment: @ikrase - afaik all those precious metals are IN the Ni-Fe. Extracting them appears very difficult. At this point they are not economically viable either - nothing is. I am not convinced refining in space is within our abilities but getting Ni-Fe from mine to Earth orbit and orbit to ground might be.

Comment: The economy would come from people wanting to build large equipment in space. This wouldn't necessarily require a large infrastructure or existing space economy to have demand.

Comment: This may be a duplicate, I'm voting to close as it needs more focus. Many things can be done if there are no limits on time or money, this question needs to put some limits on to be meaningfully answerable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get processed asteroid metals back to Earth in a safe manner](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14157/how-to-get-processed-asteroid-metals-back-to-earth-in-a-safe-manner)

Comment: The suggested "How to" Q probably makes mine a duplicate but the answers didn't really answer. HopDavid's answer was informative but I did not find it entirely satisfactory. It may be my question is too broad ranging and would better suit discussion. Underlying is trying to find genuine commercial opportunity - in Earth economy terms - in Asteroid mining by directly exploiting a commodity that is extremely abundant, (relatively) easy to extract and has (relatively) high value.

Comment: Re *perhaps several thousand US$ per ton for high nickel content would seem likely* -- On what world? Iron ore is worth US 100$ per ton today. And even if it was worth ten times that, that would still make iron ore a bulk commodity.

Comment: @DavidHammen - keep trying to answer but site keeps posting percentage and dollar signs wrong. Sixth attempt - see Fred above for over 13,000 USD per ton for nickel. Taenite contains 20-65 percent nickel, ie over 8,000 USD per ton of high nickel taenite. It could be substituted directly in high nickel steel alloys with no or minimal refining. I stand by my rough estimate of several thousand dollars per ton.

Comment: And it is the high nickel taenite that contains the higher proportions of precious Platinum Group Metals - appearing to be associated with the nickel more than the iron.